# error run-time '9' in split function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel I have create the following combo box:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ActiveSheet.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "CHIAV<-->MACC"
        .AddItem "CHIAV<-->TRISC"
        .AddItem "CHIAV<-->PITT"
    End With
End Sub
```

Its Change sub is:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim operatore As String
    Dim Op1 As String
    Dim Op2 As String
    Dim trovato As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    operatore = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
    Op1 = Split(operatore, "<")(0)
    Op2 = Split(operatore, ">")(1)
    Cells(1, 2) = Op1
    Cells(2, 2) = Op2
    trovato = 0
    If ComboBox1.Value = "SELEZIONA OPERATORI" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Non hai selezionato nessun range di celle!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each cell In rng
        If (trovato = 2) Then
            Exit For

        ElseIf StrComp(cell.Value, Op1) = 0 Then
            trovato = trovato + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    If (trovato < 2) Then
        MsgBox "Operatori non trovati nella selezione!"
        cbReset
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Select Case operatore
            Case "CHIAV<-->MACC"
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If cell.Value = "CHIAV" Then
                        cell.Value = "MACC"
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "MACC" Then
                        cell.Value = "CHIAV"
                    End If
                Next cell
                MsgBox "Scambiato CHIAV con MACC"
            Case "CHIAV<-->TRISC"
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If cell.Value = "CHIAV" Then
                        cell.Value = "TRISC"
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "TRISC" Then
                        cell.Value = "CHIAV"
                    End If
                Next cell
                MsgBox "Scambiato CHIAV con TRISC"
            Case "CHIAV<-->PITT"
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If cell.Value = "CHIAV" Then
                        cell.Value = "PITT"
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "PITT" Then
                        cell.Value = "CHIAV"
                    End If
                Next cell
                MsgBox "Scambiato CHIAV con PITT" 
        End Select
    End If
    cbReset
End Sub
```

and cbReset is the macro:

```
Sub cbReset()
 'Reset ComboBox1 Values
      ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Value = "SELEZIONA OPERATORI"
      ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The program does what I wrote but after I select an item, the error appear in the statement "Op2 = Split(operatore, ">")(1)". I can't understand what I'm wrong. The split function shouldn't prompt error because the symbol ">" is in the string "operatore". Can somebody help me to understand?

Comment: Code (at least down to the part you say fails) works for me.

Comment: No, I take that back.  I didn't try the reset.  The reset value doesn't have a `>` in it, so will crash when you try to take the portion after the `>` from `"SELEZIONA OPERATORI"`.

Comment: I had not really noticed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by trying to find the portion of the ComboBox value after the `>` when there is no such character in the string `"SELEZIONA OPERATORI"`.

You should move the test for the "default"(?) value prior to any operation being performed:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim operatore As String
    Dim Op1 As String
    Dim Op2 As String
    Dim trovato As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    If ComboBox1.Value = "SELEZIONA OPERATORI" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Selection
    operatore = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
    Op1 = Split(operatore, "<")(0)
    Op2 = Split(operatore, ">")(1)
    Cells(1, 2) = Op1
    Cells(2, 2) = Op2
    trovato = 0

    '...
```

---

Alternatively, as mentioned by [K.Dᴀᴠɪs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781745/k-d%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%A0%C9%AAs), a more generic way of ensuring you don't create an error is to test for the existence of the delimiter prior to trying to access the portion of the string after the delimiter.  (Obtaining the portion *before* the delimiter is safe to do, even when the delimiter doesn't exist.)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim operatore As String
    Dim Op1 As String
    Dim Op2 As String
    Dim trovato As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection
    operatore = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
    'Note: It's usually better to use the full delimiter rather than just a part of it
    Op1 = Split(operatore, "<-->")(0)
    If Instr(operatore, "<-->") > 0 Then
        Op2 = Split(operatore, "<-->")(1)
    Else
        Op2 = ""
    End If
    Cells(1, 2) = Op1
    Cells(2, 2) = Op2
    trovato = 0

    If ComboBox1.Value = "SELEZIONA OPERATORI" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '...
```

Comment: You could always use `InStr()` to check if the string contains the delimiter before trying to use in `Split()`.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs In this case, the OP knows the specific values that will be in the ComboBox, and they were already performing an `Exit Sub` if the value was the reset value (I guess it means "select operation" or something), so it seemed easiest just to move that test earlier.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs No, it's a good point, so I am going to edit that in as an alternative way of testing.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs No, accessing position 0 of the array is still valid - e.g. `Split("SELEZIONA OPERATORI", "<-->")` will create an array dimensioned `0 To 0`, and position 0 of that array will contain `"SELEZIONA OPERATORI"` (i.e. everything prior to the first or, in this case, non-existent delimiter).  That's why I said "Obtaining the portion before the delimiter is safe to do, even when the delimiter doesn't exist."